# ProGuard + Maven with Java 7

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I'm trying to make ProGuard part of our Maven build process. The problem is that the official Maven plugin is using ProGuard 4.3, which doesn't support Java 7. Is there any easy way to make the plugin use Proguard 4.8 instead?

I've tried specifying the dependency for the plugin but ProGuard seems to have a new structure for Maven-modules (proguard-base, proguard-parent etc) so the plugin can't use any version >4.4. Here's how my current pom looks:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <proguardVersion>4.8</proguardVersion>
                    <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                    <options>
                        <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                        <option>-keep public class com.degoo.ui.ClientBackendStarter { public *; public static *; }</option>
                    </options>
                    <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                    <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-small.jar</outjar>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    <libs>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
                    </libs>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
                        <version>4.8</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The structure of ProGuard itself (and its jars) hasn't changed, so from that side, upgrading should be trivial. I don't know about Maven or its plugins though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/pyx4me-users/NUZi1oySvQE. Basically I had to download and install ProGuard to my local repo.

Answer (score 23):

I use the proguard-maven-plugin from `com.github.wvengen`. Note the different `groupId`. That way I can use the latest `proguard-base` artifact 5.0. Both are in Maven Central. Here's how the proguard-base portion in my pom.xml looks right now:

Parent pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.8</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
[...]
```

Here's the rest from my child pom.xml, but you probably want to modify that:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-classes-with-proguard</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <maxMemory>256m</maxMemory>
                        <injar>classes</injar>
                        <libs>
                            <lib>${rt.jar.path}</lib>
                            <lib>${jsse.jar.path}</lib>
                        </libs>
                        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                        <attach>true</attach>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <proguardInclude>${project.basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

**UPDATE:** For my Android projects I'm not using a dedicated Proguard plugin like proguard-maven-plugin since the android-maven-plugin handles the ProGuard obfuscation itself, and is integrated better into the build process for Android.

Comment: this works because of the 4.9 version that is used for java 7

Answer (score 7):

There is a fork of original [proguard-maven-plugin](http://pyx4me.com/pyx4me-maven-plugins/proguard-maven-plugin/). It's [git-hubed](https://github.com/wvengen/proguard-maven-plugin). Please see [how you do it](http://jinahya.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/profiling-the-bootstrap-classes-for-proguard-in-maven/).

**[Here](http://jinahya.wordpress.com/2013/08/02/proguard-with-maven/)** comes the latest example how we do it. **No more profiles required.**