# How to obfuscate one jar from war using proguard and maven

Tags: java, maven, obfuscation, proguard

I'm a little puzzled by proguard.
I have this setting in my pom.xml
Firstly, < injar > tag doesn't work...final call of proguard doesn't contain -injars if I use this tag.
Secondly, I'm not sure if it's possible to obfuscate only one jar that takes place in WEB-INF/lib(I compile all my code in the one jar) and filter every other libs.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
        <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>proguard</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <proguardVersion>4.8</proguardVersion>
            <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
            <maxMemory>1024m</maxMemory>
            <includeDependency>false</includeDependency> 
            <options>
                <option>-injars target/Test.war</option>
                <option>-ignorewarnings</option>
            </options>
            <outjar>target/Test-obf.war</outjar> 

            <attach>false</attach>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <proguardInclude>${basedir}\proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
        </libs>
        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
        <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

With that configuration I have a lot of warnings cause it seems that proguard tries to obfuscate every jar in WEB-INF/lib
Could someone spread the light on that. Thank you in advance.

**Added:** 
The problem with output that stands in front of all parameters was very tricky for me. As I understood you should not use ${basedir} when you specify both injars and outjars in pom.xml. Cause ${basedir} turns to absolute path and intenaly proguard also put an absolute path.

Comment: btw, references to external libs should be specified with `-libraryjars` option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I have never used ProGuard from Maven, only from Ant.

I compare your configuration file with one in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929236/proguard-maven-with-java-7)

```
 <options>
     <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
     <option>-keep public class com.degoo.ui.ClientBackendStarter { public *; public static *; }</option>
 </options>
 <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
 <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-small.jar</outjar>
```

In your case you configure `injars` and `outjar` in different manner which is strange to see.

> (I compile all my code in the one jar) and filter every other libs.
>    I have a lot of warnings cause it seems that proguard tries to obfuscate every jar in WEB-INF/lib

In that case warnings come not from the fact that ProGuard tries to compile all the libs, but because when it obfuscates your filtered code it wants to see reference to extarnal libs. [See this.](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/introduction.html)

You would need to add for every external jar referenced in your code

```
<lib>path/lib.jar</lib>
```

This would probably help you to avoid many warning, but the real art start when you configure `-keep` options.
I would recommend to start with this configuration https://stackoverflow.com/a/7511926/1360074
If that works eventually try to get more obfuscation.

Comment: about different ways injar and outjar - it is a first part of my question. With < injar > tag I don't have -injar option in my final proguard call. About <lib></lib> it's clear for me when I need to obfuscate 1 separate jar. But all my libs and code are insight war file. How to filter only one my jar? Or maybe I need to obfuscate my jar before packaging it into war?

Comment: @FedorSkrynnikov Obfuscate that jar before you put it inside war.

Comment: I've changed phase to prepare-package but still com.pyx4me doesn't pass injar that I have specified before outjar. And this causes java.io.IOException: The input doesn't contain any classes. Did you specify the proper '-injars' options?

Comment: @FedorSkrynnikov, try to obfuscate first without Maven, with normal Proguard using config file in the answer. Once it works, move configuration to Maven.

Comment: Yes. I did that. In gui tool proguard obfuscates with out any error. But while I'm trying to use it through maven it passes -outputjar before anything I've specified in pom.xml. And it causes 'The input doesn't contain any classes' error

Comment: @FedorSkrynnikov, then try to obfuscate without GUI to understand more about options, and please specify updated maven script.

Comment: The problem with output was very tricky for me. As I understood you should not use ${basedir} when you specify both injars and outjars in pom.xml. Cause ${basedir} turns to absolute path and intenaly proguard also put an absolute path. Anyway thanks for your support. I'll accept your answer.